# Typescript: How to dynamic access interface property when string index is not allowed?

Tags: typescript, strict

I've got the following interface. Variable access like metrics[ key[1] ] is not allowed because not string indexable. Is there another way to access a single element dynamically, like metrics.{key[1]}? Or a way to make it string indexable while keeping it's structure?

```
export interface Metrics {
  bufferLevel?: { audio: number, video: number };
  bitrateDownload?: { audio: number, video: number };
  qualityIndex?: { audio: number, video: number };
  qualityIndexPending?: { audio: number, video: number };
  qualityIndexMax?: { audio: number, video: number };
  droppedFrames?: { audio: number, video: number };
  latency?: {
    audio: { min: number, avg: number, max: number },
    video: { min: number, avg: number, max: number }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting out with a string type, you can narrow it down to one of the `Metrics` keys allowed and then use bracket notation:

```
declare const metrics: Metrics;
const isValidMetricsKey = (str: string): str is keyof Metrics => ['bufferLevel', 'bitrateDownload', 'qualityIndex', 'qualityIndexPending', 'qualityIndexMax', 'droppedFrames', 'latency'].includes(str);
const str: string = 'foo';
if (isValidMetricsKey(str)) {
   console.log(metrics[str]);
}
```

Comment: Ok I see. But then I would have to do that for the .audio .video .min .avg .max keys as well. That is a lot of type checking while the keys already come from a list of valid keys. No other way than using // @ts-ignore then?

Comment: If you're sure that the accesses that will be attempted are all type-correct without carrying out the checks, you could use `as` to tell TS that there's no need to check them, eg `metrics[str as keyof Metrics]` - but ideally you'd have the strings typed as proper properties *in the first place*, avoiding the need for this sort of thing.

Comment: I see. Will have a look at the key typing then. Thank U!